# How to fix Assertion error 400 in the following problem?

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, django-testing, django-tests

I am working on Django project.
I am writing a test case for the following model:

```
class Meeting(models.Model):
    team = models.OneToOneField("Team", on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    created_at = models.DateTimeField()

    def __str__(self) -> str:
        return self.team.name
```

The code for Test case is as follows:

```
class MeetingTestCase(BaseTestCase):

    def test_meeting_post(self):
        self.client.force_login(self.owner)
        meeting_data = {
            "team": self.team.id,
            "created_at": "2023-01-12T01:52:00+05:00"
        }
        response = self.client.post("/api/meeting/", data=meeting_data)
        self.assertEqual(response.status_code, status.HTTP_201_CREATED)
```

Inside .setup() function, I have created a team object:

```
self.team = factories.TeamFactory(name="Team", organization=self.organization)
```

This is my factory class:

```
class TeamFactory(factory.django.DjangoModelFactory):
    class Meta:
        model = models.Team
```

But My test case is failing and I have following assertion error:

```
self.assertEqual(response.status_code, status.HTTP_201_CREATED)
AssertionError: 400 != 201
```

which means there is something wrong with my request. What wrong am I doing?

Comment: you have to create instance of Team model using baker library and then instance id you have to provide

Comment: If Team id is UUID (or any other non-basic type), wrong serialization could produce 400. Also, OneToOneField seems wrong here - besides obvious, it also means 1 team can have 1 and only 1 meeting.

Comment: try print `response.text` or `response.body` idk. there must be text error by serializer, if you use it

Answer (score 0):

The error was fixed. Field team can have unique values only. I was creating another object in setup() method which was creating same team object, due to which I was getting error that the team field cannot have duplicate values.